# Question about $ \{ p_n (x) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} [x] $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\{ p_n (x) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} [x]$, be a sequence such that for all integers $N \geq 0$, there exists $\alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that: 
$$p_0(\alpha_N) =0, p_1(\alpha_N) =0, \cdots, p_N(\alpha_N) = 0$$ 
Show that there exists $p(x)$, with degree higher or equal to one, such that $\forall n\geq 0, p(x) \vert p_n(x)$.

I tried to think about ideals, showing that they all are cointained in a principal ideal, and then showing that it is proper. But I'm not sure if this is possible and I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: By "sequence" you mean "ordered set," correct? This is false for sequences, for example if $p_n(x)=x-\alpha$ for all $n$.

Comment: $p_n$ must have rational coefficients

Comment: Last I checked rational numbers were in $\mathbb{C}$ as well.

Comment: If all $p_n$ are equal then the $p(x)$ is $p_0$

Comment: But it doesn't have degree higher than 1.

Comment: Oh! My bad it's supposed to say higher or equal

Comment: I edited already, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all $p_n$ are $0$ this is obvious. Otherwise the number of possible distinct such $\alpha_N$ is bounded by the degree of the first nonzero polynomial in the sequence, and is in particular finite if any such nonzero polynomials exist. Thus there must be an $\alpha$ such that $\alpha_N=\alpha$ for infinitely many $N$, so all $p_n$ have $\alpha$ as a root and hence are divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.